# Writing array to CSV, unexpected behaviour for col.names = F

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to write an array to a CSV without the row and column names. Setting the column names to false doesnt seem to work. I get "x" for the column name and a warning.

Any ideas how to remove this "x"?

```
write.csv(1:5, row.names = F, col.names = F)

# "x"
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# Warning message:
#   In write.csv(1:5, row.names = F, col.names = F) :
#   attempt to set 'col.names' ignored
```

Comment: Try with `write.csv(1:5, row.names = FALSE, col.names = NULL)`, `write.csv` calls `write.table` and you can confirm this in the function body

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`?write.csv` tells us that among other things, for the arguments to write.csv:

> append, col.names, sep, dec and qmethod
>   cannot be altered

The way to get round this is to use the more general version, write.table.

```
write.table(1:5, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep=',')
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

Comment: help(write.csv): "write.csv and write.csv2 provide convenience wrappers for writing CSV files. [...] These wrappers are **deliberately inflexible**: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file. Attempts to change append, col.names, sep, dec or qmethod are ignored, with a warning."